# Upload images to Imgur with Dropzone.JS

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js, imgur

I've made a page where the users of the site can upload a picture with drag 'n drop. For this I use Dropzone.JS *(go to [infosite](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) or [Github](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/))* and I will upload the files to Imgur.

The problem is that I didn't know how I can do this with DropZone.JS. Here is my code I use for implement the `Dropzone`-class.

```
<div class="dropzone">
    <div class="fallback">
        <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
    </div>
</div>

<script src="~/Scripts/DropZone.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    

<script>
    var myDropzone = new Dropzone(".dropzone", { 
        url: "https://api.imgur.com/3/image", 
        Authorization: 'Client-ID MY_CLIENT_ID'
    });
</script>
```

Here is the response I get from Imgur

```
{
    "data": {
        "error": "An image ID is required for a GET request to /image",
        "request": "/3/image",
        "method": "GET"
    },
    "success": false,
    "status": 400
}
```

With this error:

> `XMLHttpRequest` cannot load *https://api.imgur.com/3/image*. Request header field `Cache-Control` is not allowed by `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` in preflight response.

I will also if the request succeed, get the url of the uploaded image from Imgur.

Comment: Looks like you might have a CORS issue please check the answer to this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25427627/cors-issues-with-jquery-dropzone-and-upload-to-imgur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By trying some code in the file Dropzone.js, I finally found it! I've added this line of code:

```
formData.append('image', file);
```

Also thanks to Wenceslao Negrete for his or her answer.

Comment: Please could you explain your solution?

Comment: The correct answer would be using paramName config and set it to "image". But I have not tried multiple file upload.

Answer (score 4):

If the CORS-enabled service from imgur does not include "Cache-Control" via its Access-Control-Allow-Headers: response header, the CORS requirements are not satisfied and the request is rejected by the browser.

Try this instead:

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone('.dropzone', {
    //...
    headers: {
        'Authorization': authorizationHeader,
        'Cache-Control': null,
        'X-Requested-With': null
    }
});
```

Comment: Oke, one step closer but now I've this response from Imgur `{"data": {"error": "No image data was sent to the upload api", "request": "/3/upload", "method": "POST"}, "success": false, "status": 400}`

Comment: With `//...` I mean:

    var myDropzone = new Dropzone('.dropzone', {
        url: "https://api.imgur.com/3/image", 
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'Client-ID MY_CLIENT_ID',
            'Cache-Control': null,
            'X-Requested-With': null
        }
    });